# Merging databases with similar tables structures into one single database

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I got two databases with similar data structures. They are basically archived databases having same tables but one having slightly updated data. I want to merge them both into one single database.

When I was trying to merge them both I am facing error saying duplicate data cannot be copied. But i want to copy duplicate data too. I believe this error is mainly due to primary key constraint.

Can anyone please suggest me how to club two databases without losing duplicate data in it?

For example:

Table1:

```
MemberID Name   Class   Year
120      Sam    B       2005
121      Mark   A       2005
122      John   A       2005
```

Table2:

```
MemberID Name  Class    Year
120      Sam    B       2006
121      Mark   A       2006
123      David  C       2006
```

Result table should be:

```
MemberID Name   Class   Year
120      Sam    B       2005
120      Sam    B       2006
121      Mark   A       2005
121      Mark   A       2006
122      John   A       2005
123      David  C       2006
```

Note: `memberID` is the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys must be unique.  So you need to change the design of the result table so it has some other primary key, such as a field called "ID" that is an identity field (autonumber).

When MemberID is no longer primary, then your insert should work.

You could also add another field to the result table that would indicate if it is archived, then make the primary key a combination of MemberID and archived data.  There are many ways to do this, but somehow MemberID cannot be primary in the results table.